# Python, moving object in xy axis

Tags: python, pyglet

So, i'm doing little game with python and pyglet, but i'm stuck with moving the object in xy axis.
I have object A which is dictionary, it has x-coordinate, y-coordinate and speedvectors for x and y.

When i launch this object A it flies like it should, the problem is i'm moving it like this.

```
objectA["y"] = objectA.get("y") + objectA.get("ySpeed")
objectA["x"] = objectA.get("x") + objectA.get("xSpeed")
```

So the coordinates are moving rapidly like first objextA x is 130 then its 160 etc. When i'm trying to do some collision things, object wont stop because it doesn't register hit, it skips over the block (or atleast i think it does so). Any tips how i should actually do this?

Comment: The issue is likely that the objects are going so fast that they completely cross over one another in less than a single frame of the physics engine. See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18604 for common solutions to this problem.

Comment: Also, your formula should be `xPos = xPos + xSpeed * deltaTime` where `deltaTime` is the time since last update. This prevents superfast speed when cpu has less load and slow speed on high load.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I tested it in an empty script and it worked fine

Try this in a empty script and look at the results. It should first print 0 and then print 10:

```
objectA = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "xSpeed": 1, "ySpeed": 1}

print(objectA["x"])

for _ in range(10):
    objectA["x"] = objectA.get("x") + objectA.get("xSpeed")

print(objectA["x"])
```

It might be something else in your code that causes the problem.

Btw, this is a shorter way of writing your posted code (it does exactly the same):

```
objectA["x"] += objectA["xSpeed"]
objectA["y"] += objectA["ySpeed"]
```

Comment: OP is using [pyglet](http://pyglet.org/), not regular python dictionaries. The problem isn't with the calculations of the XY coordinates, but rather with the collision check between objects.